# Invalid Sequence name in Oracle db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle

Recently , I am facing an issue with sequence in Oracle.

```
alter sequence seq_name increment by 100
```

will give me an error "Invalid sequence name"

However, if I changed it to

```
alter sequence "seq_name" increment by 100
```

It will work perfectly fine. Anyone is able to explain the rational behind this?

Thanks
Sebastian

*ps. I am using rails with oci8 to create my oracle tables.*

Comment: While creating the sequence you have created as create sequence "seq_name". thats why its expecting " while altering it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence was created with case-sensitive name (using quatation marks), so you can refer to it only with strict name - in quotation marks. If you want to refer to it without such problems just create sequence not using quotation marks. Examples below (with table name):

```
SQL> create table "t1"(c int);

Table created.

SQL> select * from t1;
select * from t1
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "t1";

no rows selected

SQL> select * from "T1";
select * from "T1"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> create table t2(c int);

Table created.

SQL> select * from t2;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from T2;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from "t2";
select * from "t2"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "T2"; -- name without quatation marks is uppercase by default

no rows selected
```

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle folds all identifiers to upper case (per the SQL standard) unless they're double quoted. ActiveRecord will create all columns, tables, ... with double quoted lower case names so you're stuck double quoting the identifiers everywhere.

Comment: is there any work around? in any case, does anyone know how to escape a double quote in rails statement. I am stuck with something like execute "select * from \"table\"" and it will throw an error

Comment: You just have to remove this quoutes from table name and write `select * from table`, but I don't know wheter it's possible and how to do it, because I don't know ruby on rails at all. I think you can post new question asking how to create non case-sensitive name in this technologdy.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence was created as lowercase. Like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "seq_name"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL ;
```

Example:

```
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name='SEQ_NAME'; --No rows selected
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name='seq_name'; -- 1 row
```

If you create with name : "SEQ_name".

```
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name='SEQ_name'; -- 1 row
```

Because, 
when you create an object (with object name enclosed with double quotes) it will store/create as it is. Without double quotes, it would be uppercase.